# JSON Key Values returning errors in Python

Tags: python, json, numpy

I have a script which I am hoping to use with NumPy to create an a feature class in a geodatabase.  A couple of things are going on, when I send my request, the associated json data that I send to the server is different than my response, thus I have not been able to determine what my key values are, if any.  I would ultimately like to have a key value and loop through the nested items to be used as fields in a feature class.

code:

```
import requests
import json
import jsonpickle
import arcpy
import json
import numpy
import requests


fc = "C:\MYLATesting.gdb\MYLA311"
if arcpy.Exists(fc):
  arcpy.Delete_management(fc)

f = open('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\myla311.json', 'r')

data = jsonpickle.encode( jsonpickle.decode(f.read()) )

url = "myURL.com"
headers = {'Content-type': 'text/plain', 'Accept': '/'}

r = requests.post(url)

parsed_json = r.json()

sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)

response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
f.close()

ndtype = numpy.dtype([
    ('Comment', 'S48')
])

vehicles = []
for item in parsed_json["La311ServiceRequestNotes"]:
    vehicles.append(tuple(item[k] for k in ndtype.names))

narr = numpy.array(vehicles,  ndtype)
arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToFeatureClass(narr, fc, [34.1728677, -118.5389413], sr)


print response.text
```

**JSON sent to server:**

```
   {
        "MetaData": {},
        "RequestSpecificDetail": {
            "ParentSRNumberForLink": ""
        },
        "SRData": {
            "Anonymous": "Y",
            "Assignee": "",
            "CreatedByUserLogin": "",
            "CustomerAccessNumber": "",
            "LADWPAccountNo": "",
            "Language": "English",
            "ListOfLa311GisLayer": {},
            "ListOfLa311ServiceRequestNotes": {
                "La311ServiceRequestNotes": [
                    {
                        "Comment": "hxhdudi",
                        "CommentType": "Feedback",
                        "FeedbackSRType": "Weed Abatement for Pvt Parcels",
                        "IsSrNoAvailable": "N"
                    },
                    {
                        "Comment": "",
                        "CommentType": "External",
                        "CreatedByUser": "",
                        "IsSrNoAvailable": "N"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "LoginUser": "",
            "MobilOS": "Android",
            "NewContactEmail": "",
            "NewContactFirstName": "",
            "NewContactLastName": "",
            "NewContactPhone": "",
            "Owner": "Other",
            "ParentSRNumber": "",
            "Priority": "Normal",
            "SRCommunityPoliceStation": "RAMPART",
            "SRType": "Feedback",
            "ServiceDate": "01/22/2015",
            "Source": "Mobile App",
            "Status": "Open",
            "UpdatedByUserLogin": ""
        }
    }
```

**Error:**

```
 line 37, in <module>
    for item in parsed_json["La311ServiceRequestNotes"]:
KeyError: 'La311ServiceRequestNotes'
```

**Sample of successful request output using only requests module and JSON as data to submit POST request:**

```
{"status":{"code":311,"message":"Service Request Successfully Submited","cause":""},"Response":{"PrimaryRowId":"1-3J1UX","ListOfServiceRequest":{"ServiceRequest":[{"SRNumber":"1-5927721"}]}}}
```

**For testing purposes I would at least like to write the output SRNumber to my feature class.**

Comment: What does parsed_json look like?

Comment: You are not posting *anything* here: `requests.post(url)`. You are not passing in data or headers.

Comment: Your `parsed_json` variable contains the response json. Can you post the response of the first request in your question?

Comment: @thiruvenkadam: the first request won't produce anything sensible, probably, since the `POST` body sent is going to be empty.

Comment: I was hoping that the first request might give the complete metadata and the second one is more kind of a filtered out response. If not, the `parsed_json` should be for `response.json()` and not `r.json()` and should be given at a later stage

Comment: There is no parsed json, I was passing that parameter to parse the data

Answer (score 0):

Don't you first need to select the `SRData` dictionary?

```
parsed_json["SRData"]["La311ServiceRequestNotes"]
```

---

Just what is `parsed_json`?  Since it is giving you a KeyError, it is a dictionary.  What are its keys?

Comment: I misread this, however setting my parsed json to `parsed_json = ["SRData"]["La311ServiceRequestNotes"]` throws  `parsed_json = ["SRData"] ["La311ServiceRequestNotes"]`
`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str'`

Comment: What is `= ['...']` supposed to do?

Comment: That's the problem with the parsed_json, I have not been able to figure out the keys.